# WordPress how to pull category specific sidebars into theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories, sidebar, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to have our WP theme call in a specific sidebar when the user lands on a dedicated `article/permalink` page. The post category will determine which sidebar is pulled in.

Example: If the user arrives on a `permalink/dedicated article` page for a post categorized as "red", then the theme would look for the post category, acknowledged that the category is red, and then find and pull in the sidebar that I have defined as "red".

Just getting started with this project and would appreciate any thoughts on what I describe below.

This is what I think the code should look like to achieve that:

```php
<?php 
if (is_category()){  
    $current_cat = intval( get_query_var('cat') );  
    get_sidebar($current_cat);  //for category red get sidebar-red.php
} 
?>
```

One more piece to the puzzle:

I want to add in an addition argument so that if the post is uncategorized (i.e. we did not categorize the post for whatever reason) that it will pull in a default sidebar. I think that code should like something like this, but I don't know how to define "non-existent category". Basically I want to tell wordpress to look for the post category. If it finds that one does not exist, then I want it to pull in sidebar-default.php

```
<?php
if (is_category()){  
   $current_cat = intval( get_query_var('cat') );  
   get_sidebar($current_cat); } 

elseif (is_category(**argument for nonexistent category**))   
   $current_cat = intval( get_query_var('cat') );  
   get_sidebar-default.php;  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `in_category` not `is`.

For example:

```
<?php
if ( in_category('fruit') ) {
    get_sidebar('1');
} elseif ( in_category('vegetables') ) {
    get_sidebar('2');
} else {
    // do nothing or something
            // ...
}
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

```
<?php in_category( $category, $_post ) ?>
```

`$category`

> (mixed) (required) One or more categories specified by ID
>   (integer), name or slug (string), or an array of these
>       Default: None

Comment: Do you think this would work just as well?

<?php get_the_category( $id ) ?>
<?php require_once('sidebar_' . $category->cat_ID . '.php') ?>

Comment: Ya that would be fine imo, just add some conditional checks to check if it is set/exists before the include/require.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the different sidebar classes defined in your CSS.

Give the category that you want to match up with the style the same name as that category's slug. In your template, define the sidebar div's class using the post's category-slug.

Here's a bit on how to get the slug:

```
<?php
if (is_category( )) {
$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$yourcat = get_category ($cat);
echo 'the slug is '. $yourcat->slug;
}
?>
```

So your sidebar div would be something like:

```
<div class="<?php echo yourcat->slug; ?> sidebar"></div>
```

So you've given your sidebar two classes, one called `sidebar` and one to be determined by whatever the category is!

Hopefully this made sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use [Category Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates), so you create category-red.php and category-blue.php files